# Spring can not automatically inject dubbo service

Tags: java, spring, rpc

Development tools: idea java

Use the framework: spring + springmvc + mybatis + dubbo

dubbo is a high-performance, java based, open source RPC framework.
When I use spring `@autowired` error, as shown in **Figure 1**.
But when I was in java annotations, it works fine, as shown in **Figure II**.
   [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL52o.png)
   [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOvMC.png)

code1.  the spring/applicationContext-service.xml  for service.

code2.  the spring/spring-mvc.xml for contoller.
 code3. Service 
 code4. Controller (Here's a problem, with `@autowired` can not be automatically injected)
 Thanks!

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:dubbo="http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
        http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo/dubbo.xsd ">


    <context:component-scan base-package="xyz.maojun.service"/>
    <dubbo:application name="manager"/>
    <dubbo:registry protocol="zookeeper"
                    address="localhost:2181"/>
    <dubbo:protocol name="dubbo" port="20880"/>
    <dubbo:service interface="xyz.maojun.service.ItemService" ref="itemServiceImpl"  timeout="600000"/>

</beans>
```

More code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:dubbo="http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo
        http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo/dubbo.xsd ">
<context:component-scan base-package="xyz.maojun.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix"value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
<property name="suffix"value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**"location="css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**"location="js/"/>
<dubbo:application name="manager-web"/>
<dubbo:registry protocol="zookeeper"address="localhost:2181"/>
<dubbo:reference interface="xyz.maojun.service.ItemService"id="itemService"/>
</beans>
```

ItemService code:

```
package xyz.maojun.service.impl;

import com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper;
import com.github.pagehelper.PageInfo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import xyz.maojun.common.pojo.EasyUIDateGridResult;
import xyz.maojun.mapper.TbItemMapper;
import xyz.maojun.pojo.TbItem;
import xyz.maojun.pojo.TbItemExample;
import xyz.maojun.service.ItemService;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
    @Autowired
    private TbItemMapper tbItemMapper;

    @Override
    public TbItem getItemById(long itemid) {

        TbItemExample example = new TbItemExample();
        TbItemExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();

        criteria.andIdEqualTo(itemid);

        List<TbItem> list = tbItemMapper.selectByExample(example);
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            return list.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
  package xyz.maojun.controller;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import xyz.maojun.pojo.*;
    import xyz.maojun.service.ItemService;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    @Controller
    public class ItemController {
        @Resource  // i want to use @autowired ,but it not work
        private ItemService itemService;
        @RequestMapping("/item/{itemId}")
        @ResponseBody
        public TbItem getItemById(@PathVariable long itemId) {
            TbItem tbItem = itemService.getItemById(itemId);
            return tbItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, add the relevant code as plain text. Same with errors and stacktraces

Comment: got it. I have added.thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I already got this answer, it is Intellij IDEA problem.When running the project does not have this error, I use the spring annotation, Intellij IDEA will can not find the bean then  make an error. [Ignore false positives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyaY1.png)